# Extracting variables chosen by glmnet or lars packages in r

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a large p small n problem (p>1000, n=150) and have decided to use  glmnet and lars to select possible explanatory variables (as I understand is their functionality) rather than do this manually.

I have gotten out both a lars, and a glmnet object from the functions, but now  can't figure out how to extract from those objects, the names of the coefficients / the optimal model, that the functions have chosen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `coef` function is for. See `?coef.glmnet` for more details.

```
# fit a glmnet object
obj <- glmnet(x, y)

# matrix of coefficients
# each row is a variable, each column is one step in the glmnet path
coef(obj)

# coefficients for a specific model in the glmnet sequence
coef(obj, s=obj$lambda[1])
coef(obj, s=0.01)
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I meant variable not coefficient! Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

I also think this should be easier, but here is one way assuming you know which spot one the regularization path you want to use, i.e. you know the Lambda of interest.

```
mod <- glmnet(x, y)
LambdaIndex <- 50 # just randomly picking one of the 100 Lambas tried
nonZerosIndices <- mod$beta[, LambdaIndex]!=0 
nonZeroVars <- names(mod$beta[nonZerosIndices, LambdaIndex])
```